# Fastest way to copy a single large (30,000 rows) table from one database to another?

Tags: sql-server-2005, copy, linked-server

I've got a large table in a SQL Server 2005 database and I'd like to copy it over to another database.

What's the fastest way to do this? Is there a shortcut to linking servers and doing inserts?

Comment: 30k rows isn't a very large table.  Unless you're doing this on an ongoing basis, just choose the easiest way.  It should complete within minutes, regardless of the import method.

Comment: one of our xref tables contains 78 million records as of this afternoon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EXPORT function of Sql Server Management Studio Express.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en

You need specify the destination server and tables, and the tool do all you need.

Answer (score 3):

Try a command line utility called bcp for a bulk export, and **Bulk Insert** for the import.

See [About Bulk Import and Bulk Export operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187042.aspx).

Comment: Is this the fastest and reliable way?

Comment: Honestly with software, there are probably at least a half dozen 'fast' ways to do something. It depends on your strengths. If all else fails, you could just export the table into a CSV and script the inserts.

Answer (score 1):

to improve the speed, disable all forms of logging and drop any constraints or referential integrity.

Comment: the easiest and most user friendly (in my view) in case of multi-server setup is to use SSIS on target server.  Build SSIS package with connection to source and with no data transformations (obvious) into the db on your destination server

Comment: There is no way to disable logging in SQL Server.  SIMPLE recovery simply tells the SQL Server that the log entries can be overwritten after they are checkpointed.

Comment: i never knew we cannot disable logging completely in sql server. thanks for sharing info.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to hit anyone here. But so far, I didn't find a fast way to copy table.
I am working on a big project and I usually handle table with 3-7 millions rows. When I want to back the table, my headache come.

Up to now:
1. BCP is definitively the fastest tool. But it can only handle simple datatype correctly. If you have nvarchar and has some strange chars  '"&#2. It ususally doesn't work. Due to the high risk work with bcp. I recommend you forget it but only use it for very simple table. 
It is really SUPER fast.

2. Never mention export/import wizard or command. It is one of the lowest tool I has used. And it may broke during transport.
3. So far, is fastest way is to detach you database, copy it by harddisk(usually 20M/s). Even you data occupy 6G disk. it only take 300s ~ 5 minutes. And attach it on another machine. Remove tables you don't want. If you use any method suggest by others, I promise you won't get the transmission in an hour.

Comment: This is what I'm facing... when I generate the insert scripts with Task -> Generate Scripts the resulting script is 8GB and always growing. It takes well over 12 hours to run the inserts on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think best option is to use export and import .